# GreenDao and entity inheritance

Tags: java, android, orm, greendao

My task is to make disk cache on Android OS for my application (it is some sort of messenger). I'd like to store messages in database, but have met a problem of storing different types of messages (currently 5 types of messages each type have it's own fields and they all extends base class)

GreenDao [documentation](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/modelling-entities/) says:

`Note: currently it’s impossible to have another entity as a super class (there are no polymorphic queries either)`

I am planing to have entity which almost 1 to 1 to base class, except one column - raw binary or json data in which every child class can write anything it need.

My questions are:

1. GreenDao is good solution in such case? Is there any solutions which allow not to worry about inheritance - and how much did they cost in terms of efficiency.
2. How to "serialize" data to such field (what method I should override or where I should put my code which will do all necessary things
3. How to give GreenDao correct constructor to "deserialize" Json or binary to correct class instance
4. Should I use reflection - or just switch/case for finding correct constructor (only 5 types of constructors are possible) - is reflection how much will reflection "cost" in such case?

Comment: Your classes are generatred by greendao, so why do you want a base class in first place? I suggest a interface would be sufficient.

Comment: Most time I work with the messages as the instances of base class, but sometimes I need them as concrete type - (for example: is this message incoming or outgoing in chat).

And I think to have own table for each type of message will make program more difficult and not efficient - to draw dialog on the screen it will be necessary to access multiply tables...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need inheritance greendao is not the r I get choice, since it doesn't support it. But I think you can go without inheritance:

You can design an entity with a discriminator column (messagetype) and a binary or text column (data). Then you can use an abstract factory to create desired objects from data depending of the messagetype.

If the conversion is complex, I'd put it in a separate class, otherwise I'd put it as a method in the keep section.

Be aware that this design may slow you down, if you really have a lot of messages, since separate tables would reduce index sizes.
Talking about indexes: if you want to access a message through some property of your data column later on, you are screwed since you can't put an index on it.

Comment: Yep, I make it in such way - just created a ORM for basic class and String(JSON-format) for each subclass which inherits base class

Comment: To prevent to often parsing of JSON object  - instance of inherited class is created on base of instance of ORM class and caches all necessary fields